# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.5

I need to get the UserId Guid directly after a successful login. The following code doesn't work:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Value, txtPassword.Value))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // doesn't run
        Guid puk = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;            
    }
}
```

The following code does work:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Value, txtPassword.Value))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);

    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(txtUsername.Value);

    if (user != null)
    {
        Guid puk = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there something more to do besides `SetAuthCookie`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because when you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);` you store the key on the client's cookies. For this you need to do a response to the user.
And for `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` to be filled with cookie you need one more request.

In short your scheme looks like this:

1. Client sends his UserName and Password.
2. Server gets and checks it. If they are valid the server sends `Set-Cookie` header to the client.
3. Client receives and stores it. For each request client sends cookies back to the server.

UPDATE for @Jake

Adding an example of setting `User` in `HttpContext`

```
var identity = new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(user.UserName);
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

Note that you could create your custom principal class inheriting from `GenericPrincipal` or `ClaimsPrincipal`

Comment: Is there any way to access User Identity in the same request?

Comment: @AhmadAhmadi you can set it manually assigning CustomPrincipal object to User property of HttpContext.

Comment: @OleksiiAza Could you possibly update your answer to show how to do this?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem too. I forgot to set the web.config configuration.

Maybe you missed too.

```
   <system.web> 
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/user/login" timeout="1000" name="__Auth" />
    </authentication>  
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my development environment case, requireSSL property was set to true, I fixed the problem by changing it to `requireSSL = false`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above solutions ,but the thing that solves my problem was commenting this in web.config

```
 <modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
 </modules>
```

Comment: This would remove forms authentication altogether, so of course that would let the user go by.

Comment: This didn't remove forms authentication but I'm not sure what it's doing.  The true/false is now working with that module removed;... odd?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in a Blazor .NET 6 WASM application. I followed the guide below to expose the authentication state as a cascading parameter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter

This worked well but when used with `OnInitializedAsync` `user.Identity.IsAuthenticated` was set to false after successful login but worked when the page was refreshed.

Changing component lifecycle to `OnParametersSetAsync` instead fixed the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#after-parameters-are-set-onparameterssetasync

Complete code in `MainLayout.razor`:

```
@code {
    bool loadData = true;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            loadData = true;

            await StateContainer.LoadDataAsync();

            loadData = false;
        }
        else
        {
            loadData = false;
        }
    }
}
```